# Exe file not playing QSound music

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I was working on a gui with Python's PyQt5 and I used the QSound module to play a sound. It runs fine on the script but when converted to an exe with pyinstaller the sound does not play any longer. Can I get any help?

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Comment: Something to note is, unless you tell pyinstaller to include the sound files, you still need those in the directory with the .exe file.

Comment: @Jmonsky the directory is with the .exe file

Comment: @TheOneMusic I don't have enough points to share images...I was kinda hoping someone ran into similar issue here